# Hungerford's Proof of the Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

[image]

I am having trouble seeing why $r_k \equiv 0 (\mod A_i)$ for all $i \neq k$. Showing $b_k \equiv r_k (\mod A_k)$ was pretty trivial, but the other claim is giving me trouble. I could use some help.

Comment: $r_k$ is in the intersection of all the $A_i, i\neq k$, so it is in each one.

Comment: @JohnBrevik D'oh! Thanks!